# What is your favorite resource for web site design tips? (particularly e-commerce)

Tags: e-commerce

I'm a developer, but I also have a design background; I've been asked to take over site design on the e-commerce site I've been working on for a few years now. There's a lot I'd like to change, but, the fact is, I'm primarily a software developer now.  I'm looking to get a refresher on good e-commerce site design, and I was wondering if anyone here, with a programming background like myself, knows of or uses any good resources for such a thing.

I realize that all answers I get here will be from a developer's perspective, so I'll be sure to check some business-oriented and design-oriented sites like stackoverflow to see what professionals in other areas might like to use as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, I would find out which e-commerce sites users love the most and why. For design ideas, we all know design is 90% "Inspiration" and 10% original thought. With that in mind:

I like **[Patterntap](http://patterntap.com/)** a great gallery of good site design. Particularly their e-commerce collection http://patterntap.com/tap/collection/ecommerce, but be sure to check out the user-collections.

Answer (score 2):

For ideas, I think the best resource are the e-commerce sites that exist. [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) often has articles like ["15 Common Mistakes in E-Commerce Design and How to Avoid Them"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/08/15-common-mistakes-in-e-commerce-design-and-how-to-avoid-them/).